# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'movies.csv'

Tags: python, csv, telegram, export-to-csv, python-telegram-bot

I am making a telegram bot and it takes the data of movies and puts it in a csv file which i later give for exporting,
but in my code the csv file is not getting created and if i add a pre added csv file, the data is not getting exported to it.
here is the full code

```
import os
import telebot
import requests
import json
import csv
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
# TODO: 1.1 Get your environment variables 
bot_id = os.getenv('botkey')
my_key = os.getenv('keyy')
bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_id)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'hello'])
def greet(message):
    global botRunning
    botRunning = True
    bot.reply_to(
        message, 'Hello there! I am a bot that will show mov information for you and export it in a CSV file.\n\n')
    
@bot.message_handler(commands=['stop', 'bye'])
def goodbye(message):
    global botRunning
    botRunning = False
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Bye!\nHave a good time')
    


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: botRunning, commands=['help'])
def helpProvider(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, '1.0 You can use \"/movie MOVIE_NAME\" command to get the details of a particular mov. For eg: \"/movie The Shawshank Redemption\"\n\n2.0. You can use \"/export\" command to export all the mov data in CSV format.\n\n3.0. You can use \"/stop\" or the command \"/bye\" to stop the bot.')


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: botRunning, commands=['movie'])
def getMovie(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Getting movie info...')
    mov = message.text
    mov = mov.replace("/movie","")
    response = requests.get(f'http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=a13fc218&t={mov}')
    mov_data=response.json()
    print(json.dumps(mov_data,indent = 4))
    bot.reply_to(message,f"{mov_data['Poster']} \nMovie Name: {mov_data['Title']} \nYear: {mov_data['Year']} \nReleased: {mov_data['Released']} \nImdb Rating: {mov_data['imdbRating']}")
    bot.send_photo(message,{mov_data['Poster']})
    with open('movies.csv','a',encoding='UTF8',newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow([mov_data['Title'],mov_data['Year'],mov_data['Released'],mov_data['imdbRating']])


  
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: botRunning, commands=['export'])
def getList(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Generating file...')
    chat_id = message.chat.id 
    print()
    mov_data=open('movies.csv','rb')
    bot.send_document(chat_id,mov_data)
    

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: botRunning)
def default(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'I did not understand '+'\N{confused face}')
    
bot.infinity_polling()
```

Yes, i have tried to make the location of the creation of file very specific, that didnt work as well.
I am working on a macbook.
Need help

Comment: Please provide a [_minimal_ reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: what is the purpose of `load_dotenv`?

Comment: also, `TODO: 1.1 Get your environment variables` - we don't have these

Comment: its for using the botid and the apikey using environment variables, i am concerned about the csv part i asked in the question

Comment: Is the problem with `getMovie()` or `getList()`?

Comment: @JonSG, the problem starts with the getMovie() and since the execution of getMovie() is not happening, getList() doesnt work either

Comment: Seems to work for me in a little test, what `message` seems to result in a failure for you?  Is it a movie that does not exists and you get a keyerror?

Comment: The movie details are shown, but when i put the /export command, the csv file is not getting created where the movie data we got has to be stored.
it just shows what i have put in the heading

Answer (score 0):

Does this help if you define that parameters explicitly?

```py
def getList(message):
    with open('movies.csv','rb') as movie_csv_file:
        bot.send_document(
            chat_id=message.chat.id ,
            document=movie_csv_file
            filename="all_movies.csv"
        )
```